# jqGrid - Select Menu With Special Characters

Tags: select, jqgrid, special-characters

In my jgGrid edit form I include a select menu.  The menus are built using a...

```
'key:value;key:value;key:value'
```

...string.  My values contain ';' which then breaks the menu.  My data looks like...

```
'key:some;data;key:more;data;key:even;more'
```

It's also possible that my values could contain ':' in addition.

The grid's autoencode does not help here.  I could preg_replace() before handing off to the grid.  What other ways could I solve my problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: How can I escape the ';' and ';' characters in my values or otherwise cause jqGrid to not choke?  Thank you for your time and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building the string in PHP I did the following...

```
...

//
// remove ';' and ':'
//
$value = preg_replace('/\:|\;/', '', $data['description']);

//
// turn other special chars into html entities
// for easy removal below
//
$value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);

//
// remove html entities
//
$value = preg_replace('/&#?(\d*?|\w*?);/', '', $value);

...
```

At this point $value is clean and can be appended to the 'key:value;key:value;key...' string that jqGrid uses to build a select menu.

This approach works just fine and was easy enough however it sacrificed small bits of info here and there but in my case that's no concern.

Thanks for reading, hope this helps you.